# How to get all text channels using discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I need to get all channels to make a bunker command, which makes all channels read only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Client` class contains `guilds`, which returns a list of `guild` classes that the bot is connected to. Documentation here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.guilds

Iterating over this list, each `guild` class contains `channels`, which returns a list of `Channel` classes that the server has. Documentation here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.channels

Finally, iterating over this list, you can check each `Channel` class for different properties. For example, if you want to check that the channel is text, you would use `channel.type`. Documentation here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel

A rough example of how you can make a list of all `Channel` objects with type 'Text':

```py
text_channel_list = []
for server in Client.guilds:
    for channel in server.channels:
        if str(channel.type) == 'text':
            text_channel_list.append(channel)
```

To compare to `'text'`, `channel.type` must be a string.

For older versions of `discord.py`, commonly referred to as the `async` branch, use `server` instead of `guild`.

```py
text_channel_list = []
for server in Client.servers:
    for channel in server.channels:
        if str(channel.type) == 'text':
            text_channel_list.append(channel)
```

Answer (score 23):

They changed `Client.servers` to `Client.guilds` in [newer version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) of **discord.py** (1.0).
You can also use **bot** instead of **Client** ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234778/what-are-the-differences-between-bot-and-client)).
And `guild.text_channels` to get all text channels.
For all channels you can use `bot.get_all_channels()`

```py
text_channel_list = []
for guild in bot.guilds:
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        text_channel_list.append(channel)
```

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to get only channel names in the list?

Comment: @Jonathan simply use `channel.name` for it's name or you could also convert channel object to string `str(channel)` and it will return it's name