# How to get list of all channels using discordgo?

Tags: go, discord

I would like to send a message on all text channels of my private discord server using a bot.

I have connected and can have a [`Session`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Session) object but I'm not sure how to get a list of all available channels from the [`Session`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Session).

```
dg, err := discordgo.New("Bot " + Token)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error creating Discord session,", err)
    return
}

// Open a websocket connection to Discord and begin listening.
err = dg.Open()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error opening connection,", err)
    return
}

// Get all channel ID's from dg here
```

Is this even possible with the discord API?

Comment: There are two methods called GuildChannels and UserChannels. Have you tried those?

Comment: GuildChannels requires guildID and UserChannels returns empty list

Comment: here the python api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446882/how-to-get-all-text-channels-using-discord-py
but I couldn't find anything similar in discordgo

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic `UserChannels returns an array of Channel structures for all private channels.` Are your channels private?

Comment: @reticentroot Sadly they are not. I tried using that method but it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if this is still relevant to you, but leaving this here for anyone else wondering.

All you need is access to the `discordgo.Session` object, `dg` will in your case work just the same.

It is possible, but you have to loop through each *Guild* (server) the bot has access to. Alternatively, if you have the relevant guild ID or object you can loop through the channels of only that guild.

```
func spam(s *discordgo.Session) {
    // Loop through each guild in the session
    for _, guild := range s.State.Guilds {

        // Get channels for this guild
        channels, _ := s.GuildChannels(guild.ID)

        for _, c := range channels {
            // Check if channel is a guild text channel and not a voice or DM channel
            if c.Type != discordgo.ChannelTypeGuildText {
                continue
            }

            // Send text message
            s.ChannelMessageSend(
                c.ID,
                fmt.Sprintf("testmsg (sorry for spam). Channel name is %q", c.Name),
            )
        }
    }
}
```