# What are the differences between Bot and Client?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been going through some examples on how to make a Discord Python Bot and I've been seeing `client` and `bot` being used almost interchangeably and I'm not able to find when you would use which one when.

For example:

```
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$guess'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Guess a number between 1 to 10')

    def guess_check(m):
        return m.content.isdigit()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('token')
```

vs.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description=description)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def add(left : int, right : int):
    """Adds two numbers together."""
    await bot.say(left + right)

bot.run('token')
```

I'm beginning to think they have very similar qualities and can do the same things but is a personal preference to go with a client vs. a bot. However they do have their differences where clients have an `on_message` while bots wait for a `prefix command`.

Can someone please clarify the difference between `client` and `bot`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## Tl;dr

Just use `commands.Bot`.

---

`Bot` is an extended version of `Client` (it's in a *subclass* relationship). Ie. it's an extension of Client with commands enabled, thus the name of the subdirectory `ext/commands`.

The `Bot` class inherits all the functionalities of `Client`, which means that everything you can do with `Client`, `Bot` can do it too. The most noticeable addition was becoming command-driven (`@bot.command()`), whereas you would have to manually work with handling events when using `Client`. A downside of `Bot` is that you will have to learn the additional functionalities from looking at examples or source codes since the commands extension isn't much documented. UPD: Now it is documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/).

If you simply want your bots to accept commands and handle them, it would be a lot easier to work with the `Bot` since all the handling and preprocessing are done for you. But if you're eager to write your own handles and do crazy stunts with discord.py, then by all means, use the base `Client`.

---

In case you're stumped by which to choose, I recommend you to use `commands.Bot` since it's a lot easier to work with and it's in addition of everything `Client` can already do. And please remember that you **do not need both**.

**WRONG:**

```
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(".")

# do stuff with bot
```

**CORRECT:**

```
bot = commands.Bot(".")

# do stuff with bot
```