# I have two problems with my discord.py bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

First of all, i want to know if/how i can bind this bot event to a specific channel or a specific role so this can just be executed by this role in this channel:

```
async def on_message(message):

if content.message.startswith('!Beispiel')

(return)
```

Also i want to know why my bot doesnt answer with this code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

client = discord.Client()


@bot.command()
async def temprole(ctx, role_time : int, member: discord.Member=None, role: discord.Role = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who do you want me to give a role?")
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("Ok, I did it :thumpsup:")
    if role is None:
       return await self.bot.say('Pls write a role')

    await asyncio.sleep(role_time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("The time of the role of {} is up".format(member))

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)


client.run(' ')
```

becuase im typing in !test hello or !temprole or so and it doesnt answer :/

Comment: There is no connection between your `bot` and `client`. Delete your `client` and do `bot.run(TOKEN)`.  
You can bind the bot to a specific channel or role by adding a custom check to the command. [See example of this section](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check)

Comment: Also to get an idea of `discord.Client` and `discord.ext.commands.Bot`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234778/what-are-the-differences-between-bot-and-client
It can be confusing when the tutorials switch between the two interchangably. `Bot` is a subclass/extension of `Client`. You should just use Bot throughout your code.

Comment: Sry, but my first question wasnt asnwered and also i have now the question if i can run a bot and a client at the same time with the same token?

Comment: It makes no sense to run bot and client at the same time. It would also not be possible. Bot is an extension/subclass of Client. Just use bot.  
I linked an example of how to write a custom check that makes a command only possible under custom criteria. Try to implement that and if you run into problems, make a new question with code + error traceback. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. It's nice if people do it but you can't expect people to provide you the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a client all you want is a bot `(commands)` here is how it should look.

Also you should consider learning [fstring](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) because it is much simpler to format strings

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.command()
async def temprole(ctx, role_time: int, member: discord.Member = None, role: discord.Role = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who do you want me to give a role?")
        return
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send('Pls write a role')
        return

    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Ok, I did it :thumpsup: {member.mention} is muted for {role_time}sec")

    await asyncio.sleep(role_time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"The time of the role of {member.mention} is up")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: # to skip messages from the bot
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!Beispiel'):
        await message.channel.send("Beispiel it is  ") 

    await bot.process_commands(message)# to make the bot accept commands

bot.run('TOKEN')
```