# Having problem with message sending command

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to do a repeat command with this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='V!')


@client.command(name='repeat')
async def _repeat(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

but when sending a message with a command, the bot doesnt respond neither with the wanted message, nor an error that would imply something is not right. i am also very new to programming so it may be something dumb that i do not know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually running the bot? With `client.run("TOKEN")` at the end of the file?

Comment: yes, it shows that the bot is online on discord and says that it logged into the bot

Comment: It shows *a* bot as online, but not the one you want :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine your code carefully, you'll see that you are assigning the command to the `client` object, but running the `bot` object. You need to do `client.run("<TOKEN>")` as another commenter suggested.

You also don't need `bot = discord.Client()` at all. `discord.Client` is a parent class with less abilities. I encourage you to rename `client` to `bot` though.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='V!')

@bot.command(name='repeat')
async def _repeat(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Notice now there's no `import discord` or `discord.Client` anywhere.

See: [What are the differences between Bot and Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234778/what-are-the-differences-between-bot-and-client)

Comment: I changed the places of 'client' and 'bot' but i'm experiencing the same results

Comment: I didn't say just exchange the names. The underlying issue is you've declared two objects A & B, assigned a command to A, but then ran B. Exchanging A & B alone doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: You are right, the command works after assigning the code to run both the bot and command it worked

Comment: Great to hear! TL;DR don't use `discord.Client`