# Discord bot doesnt respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my first time making a discord bot. I've followed every step of the tutorial but my bot doesnt react to the !test command. I do see the bot in the discord server. please help

[This is my first time making a discord bot. I've followed every step of the tutorial but my bot doesnt react to the !test command. I do see the bot in the discord server. please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5webp.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great guide on how to ask a good question.  Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and how to show your code, data, and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on line 15, your if statement for `if(message.content.startswith(!test):` is place after the return. The bot will never reach those lines. You will have to move the indent back (indents in python are annoying).

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
    
if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    await message.channel.send("Hello!")
await client.process_commands(message)
```

Secondly, `await client.process_commands(message)` only works with a command client and does not work with the base discord.Client(). The client would have to to be something like

```
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

See [What are the differences between Bot and Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234778/what-are-the-differences-between-bot-and-client) for the difference between discord.Client() and commands.Bot().