# Discord.py know if user exists in server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Sorry to bother everyone, I know this is duplicated but I don't have the rank to comment so I have to ask again, I've seen some other posts about this and all of them say you manually get the guild id and define it in on_ready() like:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(ID_OF_GUILD) # find ID by right clicking on server icon and choosing "copy id" at the bottom
    if guild.get_member(ID_OF_MEMBER) is not None: # find ID by right clicking on a user and choosing "copy id" at the bottom
        # the member is in the server, do something #
    else:
        # the member is not in the server, do something #
```

But how do I get the id of the guild automatically in on_message(), I would like my bot to run in various servers and as you can understand, that wouldn't really work.

If you need more context, its a bot where you have currencies and you can transfer them between users, I want to check if the user the message.author wants to transfer money to really exists.

Thanks in advance,
Noel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `on_message(message)`, you can get the guild via `message.guild`:

```py
@client.event #Maybe you use client or maybe bot, then you would have to change this to whatever of them you have
async def on_message(message):
    guild = message.guild
    if guild.get_member(ID_OF_MEMBER) is not None: # find ID by right clicking on a user and choosing "copy id" at the bottom
        # the member is in the server, do something #
    else:
        # the member is not in the server, do something #
```

To be able to use `guild.get_member`, you have to enable member intents in your [developer dashboard](https://discord.com/developers/applications) in your application under bot:
[image: Member intents]
and at the top of your code, where you define `client`, change `client = ...` to:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(... whatever you have here, intents=intents) #this line can be different for you!
```

---

References:

- [Message.guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.guild)
- [A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

Comment: I use @client.event, what is the difference? 

Comment: Nothing really, just insert `client` instead of `bot` @noelpuig

Comment: It always seems to print `None` , no matter if the user is in the server or not, I've been using the id, what should I input, the id or name?

Comment: You only have to input the id of the member. @noelpuig

Comment: well to test it out I've been manually inputing the code `guild = message.guild`,
   `print(guild.get_member(546937413684166676))` that user does exist and outputs `None`

Comment: You have to enable member intents for this to work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832812/14506951) answer for a guide to do so. @noelpuig

Comment: Hey! it worked, thanks! Just one last question, instread of `client = commands.Bot(intents = intents)` I have `client = discord.Client(intents = intents)`, it works but I'd like to ask what does that do?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51235308/14506951) explains the difference between client and bot @noelpuig