# How to get a list of people currently in a voice channel - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get a list of all users/members in the voice channel a certain user who ran the command is in. I manage to get the user and the channel he is in without any problems (tried this by sending a chat message that mentioned the channel, it worked). But when I try to get a list of the users/members connected to the channel it's starting to get weird.

```py
      await message.channel.send("called by user " + message.author.name)
      voice_state = message.author.voice
      if voice_state != None:
        channel = voice_state.channel
        await message.channel.send(channel.mention)
        await message.channel.send(len(channel.members))
        for u in channel.members:
          await message.channel.send(u.name)
      else:
        await message.channel.send("user " + message.author.name + " is not currently in a voice channel")
```

This is the code I used. `message` is the message that contained the command. This outputs the correct user and mentions the voice channel he is in (if he is in one). The next command `await message.channel.send(len(channel.members))` outputs 0 most of the time, but weirdly gave 2 (the correct number) once instead. Obviously the loop doesn't trigger if the list is of length 0. It wasn't yet implemented when it output 2 once, so I can't tell if it works as intended.

Most of this is just for testing if I get a correct list, which I don't. How can I get a list of users/members in a channel?

Comment: Where do you define `users`?

Comment: >Where do you define ```users```?
---
I didn't. This was a comment before testing it here. It is different in my actual code. Updated it here. Thanks for pointing it out. It was equal to ```channel.members```

Comment: Have you enabled `intents.members` in your dashboard and in your code?

Comment: No, I haven't. At least not consciously. What is that and what does it?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346581/discord-py-know-if-user-exists-in-server/67346612#67346612 without enabling them, you don't have access to the member list and can't query any members