# I got an error on programming a discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, attributeerror

I was programing a python discord bot. I got this error:

[image: error image]

Code:

```
    # jokeybotmain.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('ODg0NjkxODkzNTk2ODU2MzQw.YTcLiA.pKu1RIyV2HOTFhLOWQX0ryliyco')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You seem to have used your **actual token** as the environment variable name, which probably doesn't exist. Also that means you've publicly shared your credentials so now need to rotate them. The point of using env vars is to _not_ have secrets in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

## Error

---

Your problem is that you put the token (copied from discord developer portal) as a parameter for `os.getenv`.
You can instead remove the part about `dotenv` and make your bot work, like this:

```
import discord
TOKEN = "Your token here" # Remember to delete it before sending your code
# Use Bot instead of Client
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234778/what-are-the-differences-between-bot-and-client
bot = discord.Bot(prefixes=['!'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
Bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "YOUR_TOKEN"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```