# Is there a way to get bot information using the token in Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to get the bot information via the token in Discord.py, but I do not know if it is possible. I am trying to get the bot name, how many servers, and the client ID in the console.

I have tried looking for other explinations, but they did not work or were for discord.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Please read the docs thoroughly before asking related questions here. You can get information about the bot using [**`bot.application_info()`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.application_info), or [`bot.application`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.application) (which I can't get working).

I don't know what you mean by "bot name"; here's how to get them "in the console":

```py
print(f"I'm in {len(bot.guilds)} server{'s' if len(bot.guilds) != 1 else ''}.")
print(f"bot.user.name (display name without number tag): {bot.user.name}")
print(f"bot.user.display_name (display name without number tag): {bot.user.display_name}")
print(f"bot.user.mention (unique @ mention string): {bot.user.mention}")
print(f"bot.user (username with number tag): {bot.user} OR {bot.user.display_name}#{bot.user.discriminator}")

app_info = await bot.application_info()

#print(app_info == bot.application) (would return True)

print(f"bot.application_id: {bot.application_id}")
print(f"<AppInfo>.id: {app_info.id}")
print(f"<AppInfo>.name (display name without number tag): {app_info.name}")
```

As you'll see, [`bot.user.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.name), [`bot.user.display_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.display_name) and [`<AppInfo>.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AppInfo.name) are the same. [`bot.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.user) returns the full username, with the number tag ([`bot.user.discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.discriminator)). Choose which name you want to use :D

[`bot.application_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.application_id) and [`<AppInfo>.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AppInfo.id) are also same. [`bot.user.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.mention) is also the same but returns a string in the `<@id>` format, which, when sent, pings the user (in this case, the bot itself), unlike the other two which return just the integer ID.

I've commented out a line, as I can't get `bot.application` to work, as no matter what I try, my version's `Bot` and `Client` classes don't have that attribute.

The [docs about `bot.application`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.application); use it if you can figure out how to:

> The client’s application info.
>
> This is retrieved on [login()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.login) and is not updated afterwards. This
> allows populating the application_id without requiring a gateway
> connection.
>
> This is `None` if accessed before [login()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.login) is called.
>
> > **See also**
> >
> > The application_info() API call
>
> *New in version 2.0.*
>
> **Type:**
>
> Optional[ [`AppInfo`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AppInfo) ]

Here's a full example of where and how you can use the code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="", description="", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm online.") #logged in; can get application info
    print(f"I'm in {len(bot.guilds)} server{'s' if len(bot.guilds) != 1 else ''}.")
    print(f"bot.user.name (display name without number tag): {bot.user.name}")
    print(f"bot.user.display_name (display name without number tag): {bot.user.display_name}")
    print(f"bot.user.mention (unique @ mention string): {bot.user.mention}")
    print(f"bot.user (username with number tag): {bot.user} OR {bot.user.display_name}#{bot.user.discriminator}")
    
    app_info = await bot.application_info()
    
    #print(app_info == bot.application) #would return True
    
    print(f"bot.application_id: {bot.application_id}")
    print(f"<AppInfo>.id: {app_info.id}")
    print(f"<AppInfo>.name (display name without number tag): {app_info.name}")
    
bot.run("<token>")
```

I've put the code inside `on_ready()`, as you can get the application info there. I've used the [`discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) class instead of the [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client) one, as the former is a superset of the latter and has more features, so you'd want to [use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51235308/16136190).

[docs for `discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

[docs for `discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bots)