# Automatically deleting reactions on a message if the message author is equal to a username not working in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When the reaction is added, it doesn't get deleted, and there is no error anywhere.

```
@client.event
    async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
        if reaction.message.author == 'sample#0000':
            await reaction.message.clear_reactions()
```

It works without the author check. I am new to discord bots, so whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

`reaction.message.author` is of the [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) type. So, it'll never be equal to a username (with the [`discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.discriminator)/number tag).

You can use its string representation for the check:

```py
...

if str(reaction.message.author) == "sample#0000":
    await reaction.message.clear_reactions()

...
```

But as users might change their usernames, you should check their [`id`s](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.id) instead:

```py
...

if reaction.message.author.id == <integer id>:
    await reaction.message.clear_reactions()

...
```

If you want to check the username for some reason, see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76202067/16136190) for a comparison of commonly used properties of users (applicable to `Member`s) that are username strings (display names, full usernames, etc.).

From these two answers:

- [`str(<discord.Member>)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207270/16136190)
- [`<discord.Member>.id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61979530/16136190)

I've not tested the codes, but they should work fine. Also, I'm not sure if it's a big deal, but the `@client.event` should probably be indented.