# Sending messages in the on_ready? Python discord bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, python-asyncio

I want my bot to send a message when going online in the on_ready event. The line work in (on_message) but I haven't been able to make it send something in the (on_ready)

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await message.channel.send('The bot is online ')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Nothing seems wrong with the code you've posted. Could you include more context, or post an error message that you're getting?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl   Each time I run the code I get this error. **File "D:/code/python/discord test/discordtest.py", line 12, in on_ready
    await message.channel.send('The bot is online ')
NameError: name 'message' is not defined.**   I try to change `message.channel.send('The bot is online ')`  to `client .channel.send('The bot is online ')`  since `client = discord.Client()` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @ErtySeidohl With `client .channel.send('The bot is online ')` I get this error. **File "D:/code/python/discord test/discordtest.py", line 11, in on_ready
    await client.channel.send('The bot is online ')
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'channel'**

Answer (score 12):

You don't have a channel selected to send a message to. First, you need to select a channel, then you can send a message to that channel.

```
channel = client.get_channel(12324234183172)
await channel.send('hello')
```

You can get the channel ID by iterating over the list of channels in the connected server:

```
text_channel_list = []
for server in Client.servers:
    for channel in server.channels:
        if channel.type == 'Text':
            text_channel_list.append(channel)
```

From 
[How to get all text channels using discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446882/how-to-get-all-text-channels-using-discord-py)

From [How do I send a message to a specific channel?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=channel#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel) in the discord python FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

the discord.py doesn't seem to take a variable as channel

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   await client.get_channel("enter channel id here").send("bot is online")
```

I just tried it, and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

copy your user_id and paste without quotes

```
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("The bot is ready")
        print("------------------------")
        user = await client.fetch_user("User id")
        await user.send("hello")
```