# How do I make my discord bot get all text channel id's in all servers?

Tags: python, discord.py

I basically want the bot to get the channel ID of all text channels in all servers. I've looked for multiple hours but I can't seem to find anything. I'm guessing it would look something like this:

```
for server in bot.guilds:
    for channel in server.channels(Channeltype=text)
        print(channel.id)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all text channels using discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446882/how-to-get-all-text-channels-using-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

[`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.Guild) has an attribute called [`text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.Guild.text_channels).

```py
for guild in bot.guilds:
    for text_ch in guild.text_channels:
        print(text_ch.id)
```